# npm install global vs local installing different things

Tags: npm, npm-install, dependency-management

When I install a package with `--global` I get different results than when I install it locally.

**Example**
Installing https://github.com/sverweij/dependency-cruiser

```
$ npm install --save-dev dependency-cruiser
```

**I get**

```
+ dependency-cruiser@7.2.0
added 62 packages from 63 contributors and audited 491 packages in 14.511s
```

And I cannot use `depcruise` (a command explained in the repo doc)

**However**

```
$ npm install --global dependency-cruiser
```

**I get**

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\depcruise-fmt -> C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dependency-cruiser\bin\depcruise-fmt.js
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\dependency-cruiser -> C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dependency-cruiser\bin\dependency-cruise.js
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\depcruise -> C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dependency-cruiser\bin\dependency-cruise.js
C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\dependency-cruise -> C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dependency-cruiser\bin\dependency-cruise.js
+ dependency-cruiser@7.2.0
added 115 packages from 89 contributors in 18.422s
```

And then I can use `depcruise`

- Why is this happening?
- How can I get the same results (in this case the `depcruise` command) when doing a local installation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In npm, there are two ways to install things:

1. globally — This drops modules in `{prefix}/lib/node_modules`, and puts executable files in `{prefix}/bin`, where `{prefix}` is usually something like `/usr/local`. It also installs man pages in `{prefix}/share/man`, if they’re supplied.
2. locally — This installs your package in the current working directory. Node modules go in `./node_modules`, executables go in `./node_modules/.bin/`, and man pages aren’t installed at all.

That's the reason you are seeing different package size while both installation.
Reference: [Node.js Doc's](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/)

Comment: `$ ./node_modules/.bin/depcruise`  there it was! Thanks a lot :)